# Set focus text field inside dialog when dialog opened

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have custom text field and I must focus it functionality when dialog is opened. I tried focus it using vue.js `refs`:

**Code:**

```
<v-app id="app">
  <v-row align="center">
    <v-col class="text-center" cols="12">
      <v-btn color="primary" @click="openDialog()">Open dialog</v-btn>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
   <v-card>
    <v-card-title
      class="headline grey lighten-2"
      primary-title
    >
      Dialog
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="6" class="ml-2">
            <v-text-field
              ref="name"
              placeholder="Enter your name..."
              type="text"
              solo
              flat
              outlined
            ></v-text-field>
            <v-btn 
              color="indigo" 
              dark 
              @click = "setFocusName()"
             >Set focus</v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-card-text>
   </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</v-app>
```

**Javascript:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      dialog: false
    }
  },
  methods: {    
    setFocusName() {
      this.$refs.name.focus();
    },

    openDialog() {
      this.dialog = !this.dialog  
      this.setFocusName()
    }
  }
});
```

When I click to open dialog button my text field not focused. Here you can see my full [codepen](https://codepen.io/devmansurov/pen/rNajXoQ?editors=0011)

How I can focus it correctly when dialog is opened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're trying to access the `$ref` before it's actually rendered, here's a sandbox with the working code:
https://codepen.io/Djip/pen/ZEYezzm?editors=1011

To resolve the bug i've added a `setTimeout` to trigger the focus after 0.2 seconds from the open of the dialog. I first tried with `$nextTick`, but that wasn't enough to do the job - you can try adjusting the timer, to make it as low as possible.

```
setFocusName() {
  this.$refs.name.focus();
},

openDialog() {
  this.dialog = !this.dialog  
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setFocusName()
  }, 200)
}
```

Comment: thanks it's work for me but why you say that the `$ref` **name** is not allowed? In my code it is defined or I can't define `$ref`'s name as `name`?

Comment: Actually it works with the `$ref` as `name`, no idea why i didn't get that to work at the start - Will edit my answer

Comment: It worked with a timeout of 0 for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the [`autofocus`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props-autofocus) property and it will set the focus on `v-text-field` inside dialog when dialog opened:

```
<v-text-field
              autofocus
              placeholder="Enter your name..."
              type="text"
              solo
              flat
              outlined
            ></v-text-field>
```

Comment: Thank you! Just wasted an hour or two trying to mess about with nextTick. Tried chatgpt but that's f***ing useless, especially with Vue.

Answer (score 1):

I set the focus logic inside a watcher of the property that toggles the dialog.

```
watch: {
   dialog: function(value) {
      if (value) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.$refs.inputrefname.$refs.input.focus();
       });
     }
   }
}
```